# overheat after install ubuntu please

Tags: overheating

Laptop suddenly shutdown due to overheat. Before my laptop suddently shutdown, my fan run faster.
There any coding to overcome this problem?
Hp pavillion g4-2029wm
Ram 8gb
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have overheating problem with HP Pavilion g4-2002tx, it has switchable/hybrid graphics between Intel and AMD Radeon. However, it has never gotten sudden shutdown.

I just power off the AMD Radeon by sending `OFF` to `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`. Now, the thermal is about 63° C and I conclude that the problem is caused by the discrete graphics card, so just turn it off when it is not needed.

```
echo OFF | sudo tee /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

If you `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`:

- Before turning off discrete graphics (AMD Radeon):

  ```
  0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
  1:DIS: :Pwr:0000:01:00.0
  ```
- After turning off discrete graphics (AMD Radeon):

  ```
  0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
  1:DIS: :Off:0000:01:00.0
  ```

Hope it helps.